# Error while importing neurokit in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

In Jupyter notebook, I have to import neurokit.

There was this error:

> ImportError: No module named neurokit

So I tried:

```
!pip install neurokit
```

but there was another error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the error:

```
!pip install neurokit

Collecting neurokit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/e4/aac4c53fb12d52c292988897bff3d003a5798ec582b267f57057bfdf6c31/neurokit-0.2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-i17inb\neurokit\setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        long_description = open('README.md').read(),
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it as instructed in their [github page](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit.py#installation):

> ## Installation
>
> Run the following:
>
> ```
> pip install https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit.py/zipball/master
> ```

If that's still not working, try *not* using the cached copy (from your logs, you have a cached *neurokit-0.2.0.tar.gz*) and also force re-installation:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit.py/zipball/master
```

Comment: when I tried to run below command(not using cashed copy), error was,               
 "path-py 11.5.0 has requirement importlib-metadata>=0.5, but you'll have importlib-metadata 0.0.0 which is incompatible.
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\dell\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\~-mpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.IPBC74C7KURV7CB2PKT5Z5FNR3SIBV4J.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."

Comment: Here neurokit was built successfully with github master branch, but i tried to import it,  error was, Successfully built neurokit                                                                                
import neurokit as nk
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mne\utils\config.py", line 535
   print(out, end='', file=fid)                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @anandketki What is your Python version?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in installation package — they have forgotten to include `README.md` into the package. Overall, their [installation packages at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/neurokit/#history) are quite old, the latest one is from 2017 year.

Install directly from the repository:

```
pip install numpy
pip install git+https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit.py#egg=neurokit
```

Comment: I got a different error: "ImportError: No module named numpy". So I installed numpy and retried neurokit. This time it's installed. I updated the answer.

Comment: Same here, I installed numpy, but same error again. can you send me the installation steps you did from the beginning including versions and url from where you fetch neurokit package?

Comment: I didn't fetch neurokit and other packages manually — `pip` did it; most packages were fetched from PyPI, neurokit from its repository at Github. As for the commands: I created a temporary virtual environment and ran 2 commands I listed in my answer. The second one took 15-20 minutes as `pip` was busy downloading and compiling dependencies.

Comment: which python version did you use?

Comment: I tested with 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: Both were ok, no problem. The first time I stuck with "ImportError: No module named numpy" so I installed it during the process, the second time I installed it before and everything went well.